# Is there a formal, or a rigorous, definition of the 'consists in' relation?

Tags: metaphysics, mereology

Philosophers often describe one thing as consisting in some other things. However, I've never seen a rigorous definition of the 'consists in' relation. Does such a definition exist?

Comment: You can find some hints in [Object](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/object/#SubVerBunNot).

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: You can see also [Mereology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/) : "the theory of *parthood* relations: of the relations of part to whole and the relations of part to part within a whole".

Comment: @RamTobolski A search on Google for *"consists in" philosophy* will render examples unaffected by my misbeliefs about the relation. Nevertheless, I think that we may use the phrase *consists in* thus: "Persistence of personal identity consists in psychological continuity."; "Purple consists in blue and red"; "Causation consists in the interaction of forces."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You regard the relation as one between wholes and parts? Unless we regard perspectival, and conceptual, things as parts, then it would seem to me that that the set of relations between parts and wholes just includes the relations denoted by *comprises* and *constitutes*; *is a part of* and *the whole of*; as well as, perhaps, *emerges out of* and, I suppose, *immerges into*. However, I defer to your expertise.

Comment: Sorry... I'm not an "expert". It's only a suggestion for further readong and references...

Comment: All these issue are "fuzzy": this is the aim of my suggestions... We have *things* and *objects* : we have to "define" if things are only the "material" objects, and thus *objects* is a more general "category". When you speak of "Causation" this is not a (material) thing, but neither an "object", I suppose...

Comment: I would balk at someone who says purple consists in blue and red.  Once the blue and the red are mixed to make purple, there is no longer a blue and a red present.  Purple may consist *of* red and blue, but it does not consist *in* them.  Something consists in its principal parts, being changed only when those change.  But red and blue don't change, so there is no 'shepherding' of them into the whole as time continues.  And there is no gap  between all the things the purple might consist *of*, and the things that are principal and thus what it consists *in*.

Comment: @jobermark I'm not committed to the example, but it makes sense to me so long as we are talking about instances of purple. Consider that when I see purple, I actually perceive tiny bits of red and tiny bits of blue mixed together. The instance of purple that my fish exhibits would change, such that it would cease to be, if the instance of red that my fish exhibits were to change, such that it ceased to be.

Comment: In using **consists in** you are not talking about instances, you are talking about what makes purple, purple.  And that is not red and blue, it is the *quale* of purpleness.  Red and blue are like the parts of the chicken in my answer, they lack what makes a purple a purple.  If I set them next to each other, you would not have a purple.

Comment: I edited the answer to be less cutesy and point more directly at where I think the problem lies

Comment: @jobermark, I don't think there are quale for every colour one can discern. Claiming that there are that many quale involves positing more entities that we need to posit (every combination of hues multiplied by every degree of saturation multiplied by every degree of brilliance possible for each chroma) Even if that weren't the case, one can change the hue of the colour-quale by adjusting, the proportion, of the blue-quale, or of the red-quale, in the colour-quale, or by adjusting the proportion of the elements that emit, or reflect, the corresponding wavelengths in the perceived object.

Comment: Quibbling aside, you get what I mean, if purple consisted in blue and red, then whenever you found blue and red together you would have purple, which is not true.  Wherever you have an interaction of forces, there is in fact some causation, Wherever you have psychological continuity there is in fact persisence of personal identity...

Comment: Many things may be composed of he same elements, when they are composing one of those things others may be absent.  But if something consists in those elements, then wherever they are, there it is.

Comment: This has ceased to have phiolosophical content and is a question for ELU -- In fact, this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/consist-in-vs-consist-of

Answer (score 1):

Apocrypha has it that Quine used to demand he be given the collected whole comprised of the parts of a chicken (i.e. what a chicken consists in).  Given the normal thing, a slaughtered and partitioned chicken, he would complain that it was not a collected whole.  Given a live chicken he would complain that these were not the parts of a chicken, this was a chicken.  (Presumably given a dead chicken, he would claim this was not even a chicken, it was the corpse of a chicken.)

It is impossible to produce what the chicken **consists in**, without including all the things beyond that that the chicken **consist of**.  If you have any real object, and it is not a chicken, you do not really have everything that a chicken consists in.  But a real chicken contains the incidental aspects of the chicken, in addition to the aspects that really make it a chicken, so a real chicken is not what a chicken consists in either.

Various logicians, including Quine himself have tried to make sense of this idea, going back beyond Parmenides and Socrates (in Plato's dialog named after the former) discussing whether a hand is one thing or many things.  Is it *really* made up of the fingers or are they just incidental aspects of it?

To me the entire issue is an overestimation of our power to define things with a single notion.  We assume that there is some (extraordinarily complex) statement that would perfectly capture chickenhood or hand-ness.  But we are wrong, the definition of a chicken, or a hand, is a convention arrived at by iteration and approximation.

The notion of something consisting in its principal aspects is itself a weak approximation to how meaning works.  The statement itself never means anything without example, refinement or reframing.  So there is no room here for a rigorous definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "consist" expresses actually just *the identity relation* in disguise. For example, saying "being human consists in being a rational animal" is equivalent to the equality "being human = being a rational animal" or "humanity = rationality + animality".

The "consist" word is used in the context of *locating* the relevant property among other properties. For example, one considers many particular human beings. Some are short, some tall, some bald, some hairy, etc. And one wonders, where is the *humanity* in all these humans? And then one is told: "being human *consists* in being a rational animal". Then one knows better where to look, what to focus on, how to isolate the humanity within the multiplicity of human beings and their many properties.

Comment: *Consist* does express an identity relation, but it comes in two flavors.  *Consists of* means something normal and pedestrian, but *consists in* presumes some notion of 'essentiality' that is never articulated well. One can say a human consists **of** cells, without further clarification.  But one always needs to follow up an assertion of X consists in Y with a clarification as to what kind of 'essence' is being supposed.

Comment: @jober I agree that the notion "essence" is related here. I preferred to bypass the obscurity of "essence" by sticking to the clearer case of identify.

Comment: But the point is that 'consists in' is not the identity relation, it is the identity relation modulo some notion of essence.  Whether you dodge using the word or not, you are talking about the same thing.  If you discard he notion of 'essence', the concept falls apart, and can only be used metaphorically.

Comment: @jober It is difficult to say if there is a problem at all, without some specific examples.  I did ask the OP for examples, but did not get them.

Comment: He wrote back -- Nevertheless, I think that we may use the phrase consists in thus: "Persistence of personal identity consists in psychological continuity."; "Purple consists in blue and red"; "Causation consists in the interaction of forces. -- (I object to the last of these as inappropriate usage, and give the EL&U stackexchange post)  Not what you meant by examples?

Comment: @jober The OP wrote " philosophers often describe one thing as consisting in some other things". So I expect examples from philosophical texts.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose S = {1, 2, 3}.

We could say that S *consists* of the objects 1, 2 and 3.

Usually, however, this would be stated in set theory as:

For all x, x is in S if and only if x=1 or x=2 or x=3.

Comment: I don't think that the consists-in relation is the equality relation. Well suppose we say that 'Purple consists in red and blue'. I don't think that that means 'Purple equals the set that just includes red and blue'. Another example would be the claim that 'Personal identity consists in psychological continuity'.